# Could UML use User Scenario diagrams?

Tags: uml, bdd, user-experience, use-case

Surely you are familiar with UML class diagrams and object diagrams and their relationships. Object diagrams are used to model objects and their relations in a system, which for class based object oriented programming languages means modeling concrete objects of different classes.

When working on a project I had to create use cases (diagrams) and personas (as in user experience design) and I think they are in same relationship as classes and objects - instantion (instance of). Also use cases as understood in Unified Process (which is somewhat coupled with UML) are sets of scenarios with one main scenario (flow). So concrete scenario, as for example in Behaviour Driven Development is an instance of an use case.

Do you think this makes sense? Would you appreciate User Scenario Diagrams in UML for modeling personas and user scenarios, which could be used e.g. for generation of user acceptance tests as in BDD?

Comment: Parametrized use cases could be used for modeling user scenarios.
Every persona is an actor, but not every actor is a persona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guilty of over-using UML (1) in the past, including Use Case diagrams as a part of the specification.

My advise (based on experience) is that a pure textual representation, that's also executing using a BDD framework, provides the highest value/effort ratio.

1. I'm old enough to have experienced the CASE tool movement. `<shiver />`

Comment: Ok, I personally am all over textual DSLs and I totally get your point:) However, when you forget about UML concrete syntax (the diagrams), you can easily implement UML with textual notation (TextUML - http://abstratt.com/) and get productivity benefits and stay abstract syntax (xmi) compatible. Through model driven approaches, you can easily develop tools with same functionality as BDD frameworks or even better... So, my question is conceptual, I am asking if it is good idea to have such an abstraction:)

Comment: I guess it depends on the context.

Does the effort produce artifacts of high enough value to make it worthwhile for your organization?

Comment: It is just an idea of mine, I couldn't really tell, therefore I am asking, I want to know if it seems reasonable.